# Numpy behavior on indexing with range and without range

Tags: python, numpy

`arr` is of shape :`(10,4)`

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.rand(10,4)
arr[:,3] #shape (10,)

arr[:,3:] #shape (10,1)
```

shape of first is clear to me. But in second case since 3 is the last index so it's output should be similar to first one. Why is it different?

Comment: First one is indexing one specific element, 2nd one is slicing with one dimension consisting of only one element, but it wouldn't really make sense to loose dimensions automatically when slicing, because that would be unexpected behaviour

Comment: Slice indexing a list behaves the same way - returning a list rather than a single element.

Answer (score 0):

The same reason `[1,2,3][2]` is `3` but `[1,2,3][2:]` is `[3]`. You're asking for a length-1 slice, not an individual element.

Imagine how strange it would be if

```
arr[:, 0:].ndim == 2
arr[:, 1:].ndim == 2
arr[:, 2:].ndim == 2
arr[:, 3:].ndim == 1  # ?!?!
```